# Handle Exceptions from Thread in Global Exception Handler?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, exception, delphi-2010

I have a main application with a global exception handler installed. Now, for some specific exceptions being raised within another thread I want the global exception handler to be invoked. But it does only handle exceptions from the main thread. I also tried the following from within the thread but it does not work either:

```
RunInMainThread (procedure
                 begin
                 raise EExceptionFromWithinThread.Create;
                 end);
```

where `RunInMainThread` just executes the anonymous method given as a parameter in the context of the main thread.

Why doesn't this work? What's the proper way to handle such a situation?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. An exception is meant to leave the current execution point to the first matching handler for the raised exception, possibly unwinding the stack in the process. What's the point of synchronously calling an exception handler in another thread, then continuing with the next line of code? Surely there are more appropriate ways of sending information to the main thread. This looks like exception abuse to me.

Comment: I'm talking about an `ELostConnection` exception in a thread that periodically checks the network connection. An exception sounded naturally to me for this use case. What I needed would be kind of a global exception handler that handles exceptions from all threads...

Comment: This is exception abuse. By the time anything arrives in the main thread, it's no longer an exception. The main thread had to explicitly check for messages from the other threads. When it finds this "raise exception" command, it will run it, catch the exception, run the global handler, and then resume from wherever it left off (probably a call to GetMessage). The main thread won't be interrupted, and the sending thread won't do much, either. In the sending thread, just raise the exception as usual. In the OnTerminate event, check `FatalException` and handle it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this: send a message to the main thread which exception should be raised.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Any explanation why it doesn't work with `Synchronize` (being used internally by `RunInMainThread`)?

Comment: Very good idea. I would add though that it may be a good idea to use specific exception classes for this situation and to add the thread idea to message posted to the main thread. Both in order to distinguish these exceptions from exceptions raised in the main thread itself.

Answer (score 1):

I handled the exception in the thread, saving the message as a common string variable. When the status of the thread changed, I checked the variable in the main thread. Makes for very readable code.

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my framework if you are interested (http://www.csinnovations.com/framework_overview.htm).